# Creating Text Images inside of Canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, canvas

I'm looking to create a text image (multiple characters inside of an image that form a word), like the word "The Matrix" inside of a canvas that has a matrix affect. Issue I'm running into is displaying the text inside the canvas and then having a similar effect of either blinking or cascading to form the word. This is what I have so far for the canvas, without the text image.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c"),
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.height = window.innerHeight, c.width = window.innerWidth;
var matrix = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789@#$%^&*()*&^%+-/~{[|`]}";
matrix = matrix.split("");
for (var font_size = 10, columns = c.width / font_size, drops = [], x = 0; x < columns; x++) drops[x] = 1;

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)", ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height), ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0", ctx.font = font_size + "px courier";
  for (var t = 0; t < drops.length; t++) {
    var i = matrix[Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)];
    ctx.fillText(i, t * font_size, drops[t] * font_size), drops[t] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > .975 && (drops[t] = 0), drops[t]++
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 15);
```

```html
<div class="width:50%;height:25vh;background:#000;position:relative;">
  <canvas id="c" style="width:90%;height:75%;position:absolute;z-index:0;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon I have found a possible solution to your problem. It writes down the word "The matrix" but there's a small chance (7.5%) that another character will display, which will give it a blinking, decrypting effect. I kinda like it!

You can set the word to be written with the variable `textToWrite`, just above the function `drawText()`. This function loops through all the characters of `textToWrite` and passes the to the `generateChar` function. Here, the same character is returned, or, with a small chance, a random character is returned.

Back in the `drawText` function, this returned character is added to the `text` variable and written to the `<canvas>`.

Feel free to tweak the variables like you want in order to give more or less 'blinkability'.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c"),
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.height = window.innerHeight, c.width = window.innerWidth;
var matrix = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789@#$%^&*()*&^%+-/~{[|`]}";
matrix = matrix.split("");
for (var font_size = 10, columns = c.width / font_size, drops = [], x = 0; x < columns; x++) drops[x] = 1;

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)", ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height), ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0", ctx.font = font_size + "px courier";
  for (var t = 0; t < drops.length; t++) {
    var i = matrix[Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)];
    ctx.fillText(i, t * font_size, drops[t] * font_size), drops[t] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > .975 && (drops[t] = 0), drops[t]++
  }
}

let textToWrite = "The Matrix";

function drawText() {
  let textArr = textToWrite.split("");
  var text = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < textToWrite.length; i++) {
    text += generateChar(textArr[i]);
  }

  ctx.font = "60px courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText(text, c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
}

function generateChar(char, pos) {
  if (Math.random() > 0.075) {
    return char;
  } else {
    return matrix[(Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length))];
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 15);
setInterval(drawText, 30);
```

```html
<div class="width:50%;height:25vh;background:#000;position:relative;">
  <canvas id="c" style="width:90%;height:75%;position:absolute;z-index:0;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment.